# How to use cloth sim for flat surface?

Tags: physics, cloth-simulation

I'm trying to put a picnic blanket sort of thing onto a flat surface. When I do this, the cloth doesn't crumple or move (I'm guessing because there is nothing to bend it?, but I want to get a more natural and 'soft' blanket look, how would I achieve this? I have attached a picture of what it looks like now, I have the plane set to default cloth settings with 20 subdivisions and the ground set as a collision object. Sorry if this is a dumb question, I'm still really new to blender!

[image]

Comment: can u pls add a picture how it should look like? the problem with just textual picture descriptions is: it will be always vague. So one picture says more than 10.000 words...thx. Just give the pane a bit rotation and you will see "something".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a *Force Field > Turbulence* for example, here I give it a *Strength* of 2000 at the beginning, and the cloth will fold:

[image]